# Prevent rclone from re-copying files to AWS S3 Deep Archive

Tags: amazon-s3, rclone

I'm using `rclone` in order to copy some files to an S3 bucket (deep archive). The command I'm using is:

```
rclone copy --ignore-existing --progress --max-delete 0 "/var/vmail" foo-backups:foo-backups/vmail
```

This is making rclone to copy files that I know for sure that already exist in the bucket. I tried removing the `--ignore-existing` flag (which IMHO is badly named, as it does exactly the opposite of what you'd initially expect), but I still get the same behaviour.

I also tried adding `--size-only`, but the "bug" doesn't get fixed.

How can I make rclone copy only new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in rclone. https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/3834

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rclone sync`, check out https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/

> Doesn’t transfer unchanged files, testing by size and modification time or MD5SUM. Destination is updated to match source, including deleting files if necessary.

Comment: `copy`, supposedly, does the same thing. I just tried with `sync` and the result is the same.